# Deleting an Indexeddb database - Chrome getting stuck

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I have an indexeddb database that I am trying to delete programatically.

My code looks like this, however I also tried to delete it using `idb.deleteDB()` and got the exact same end behaviour:

```
                var DBOpenRequest = indexedDB.open("team-pwa"); // opening a database.

                DBOpenRequest.onerror = function(event) {
                  console.log("Error loading database");
                };

                DBOpenRequest.onblocked = function(event) {
                    console.log('blocked');
                    console.log(event);
                }
                DBOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                    console.log("success loading database");

                  db = DBOpenRequest.result;

                  db.close();
                  indexedDB.deleteDatabase('team-pwa')
                };
```

The behaviour I end up with is that I can still see the indexeddb database listed in devtools->application but if I select it, no information is displayed. This means I can't even manually delete the database any more and I have to do so through "clear browsing data".

In this state, I can't interact with the database api either. I don't get any errors, in my console, I just get... silence.

I'm getting the same behaviour on a Ubuntu machine and a Windows one.

Is this a chrome bug or am I doing something daft? Has anyone got a work around?

UPDATE: it behaves properly (no issues) in Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried "Refresh DB" in dev tools? Sounds to me like UI issue rather than db not deleted

Comment: After I've deleted as above, there is no "refresh db" button. I can't access any of the tools for the db.

It isn't just an interface problem. Once its in that state I can't create create a new database with the same name, nor can I delete the old one. I don't get any errors in the log about what's going on either. No events are triggered by indexeddb - I don't get an onsuccess, onerror or onblocking. Pure silence.